# Illegal parameter when nesting commands

Tags: macros, xstring

I keep getting illegal parameter errors when trying to define a command that contains another previously defined command. I know that you have to be careful with nested definitions, but I didn't think I was doing that. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xstring,xparse,xspace}

\NewDocumentCommand{}{\pfc}{Preface~\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}\xspace}

\NewDocumentCommand{\D}{ o }{%
\IfNoValueTF{#1} {%
\emph{D}\xspace}{%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}%
    {p}{\emph{D} \pfc}{%
        \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
            {f}{\emph{Daybreak}\xspace}%
            {g}{\emph{Morgenröte}\xspace}%
            }%
            [\emph{D}~#1\xspace]%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\D[p1]
```

I was expecting the following:

> *D* Preface 1

But I just get the illegal parameter errors. Presumably I don't want to use ##1 because I am not renewing a command within the macro. If I just put the content of \pfc instead of the command into the \D command, then it works, but I don't want to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you want `\pfc` to be? You have defined it as a command taking no arguments but used `#1` in the definition so get an error, just as you would with `\newcommand` or `\def` Possibly you want to define `\pfc` as a macro taking one argument and then use `\pfc{#1}` in your second definition, to pass that argument on.

Comment: I want \pfc just to stand in for Preface~\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}\xspace. I tried using \newcommand, but got the same error. I have used \NewDocumentCommand in the way used above to define commands that do not take arguments elsewhere and it works fine.

Comment: You can't use `#1` to pass the argument from `\D` to `\pfc`.  Either you have to define an auxiliary storage macro or define `\pfc` to take an argument and pass it through, so `\NewDocumentCommand{\pfc}{m}{...}` and then `\pfc{#1}` in the definition of `\D`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Just out of interest, why can't #1 be used to pass the argument through?

Comment: Basically when TeX sees `\foo{aaa}` where `\foo` is a macro taking one argument, it removes `\foo{aaa}` from the input stream and replaces it with the replacement text for `\foo` with `#1` replaced by `aaa` this is done _first_ then TeX starts processing that replacement text having forgotten all about `\foo`. So by the time it sees `\pfc` inside your definition and expands it, all association of `#1` to the argument of the top level command is forgotten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have defined it as a command taking no arguments but used `#1` in the definition so get an error, just as you would with `\newcommand` or `\def`.

To pass the argument of the outer command on to `\pfc` you need to define `\pfc` as a macro taking one argument and then use `\pfc{#1}` in your second definition, to pass that argument on.

So

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\pfc}{m}{... #1 ...}
```

....

```
 ....\pfc{#1}
```

Basically when TeX sees `\foo{aaa}` where `\foo` is a macro taking one argument, it removes `\foo{aaa}` from the input stream and replaces it with the replacement text for `\foo` with `#1` replaced by `aaa`. This is done *first*, then TeX starts processing that replacement text having forgotten all about `\foo`. So by the time it sees `\pfc` inside your definition and expands it, all association of `#1` to the argument of the top level command is forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

There's an obvious error in the definition of `\pfc`, which however doesn't seem a really useful command by its own.

You get a simpler implementation by fully using `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse,xspace}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\D}{ o }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {% No optional argument: just print D
    \emph{D}\xspace
   }
   {% Optional argument: pass control to an inner function
    \rowthorn_D:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \rowthorn_D:n #1
 {% Check what's the first token in the optional argument
  \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {% if it's `p', remove it and print the rest
    {p}{\emph{D}\nobreakspace Preface\nobreakspace\tl_tail:n { #1 }}
   }
   {% otherwise, if it's f or g ...
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
     {
      {f}{\emph{Daybreak}}% it's `f': print Daybreak
      {g}{\emph{Morgenr\"ote}}% it's `g': print Morgenröte
     }
     {\emph{D}\nobreakspace#1}% otherwise print the whole argument
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\D[p1] xyz

\D[f] xyz

\D xyz

\D[g] xyz

\D[ff] xyz

\end{document}
```

Note that `\xspace` is needed only in the “no optional argument” case (if ever).

[image]

Comment: The reasoning behind \pfc was that I have around 20 commands equivalent to \D for different books. If I want to change the way references to the preface of a book are formatted, I don't want to have to change all 20 commands.

Your solution, to be honest, is beyond my LaTeX level at the moment, but it looks good :)